# I get very different and inconsistent model fit indices and test statistics every time I run the cfa.mi models with the same imputed categorical data

Tags: missing-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am trying to test the measurement invariance in my one-latent-factor model. I have 24 questions coded "correct" and "incorrect" and 3 different groups in my data. The sample sizes are approximately 200 for each group.

Since there is some missing data, as far as I know, I can't run the CFA models with the WLSMV estimator. So, I first imputed the data with the `Amelia` package and then tried to run the `cfa.mi` function in the `semTools` package as stated in the `runMI` function description.

My problem is that every time I run the configural or metric model, fit indices (CFI, TLI, RMSEA) and the model test statistics yield very different results (I keep the imputed datasets the same).

Here's the code I am running:

```r
data_mck <- MCK_DATA_
data_mck <- data_mck[, 1:32] 
set.seed(12345)
Amelia.imputation <- amelia(data_mck[,-c(14,15,16,17,18)],  m = 20, 
    idvars = "ID",  ords = c("Q1", "Q2A", "Q3A", "Q3B", "Q3C", "Q5", 
    "Q6", "Q8A", "Q8B", "Q8C", "Q10", "Q12B", "Q13A", "Q13B", "Q13C", 
    "Q17A", "Q18B", "Q19A", "Q19B", "Q19C", "Q19D", "Q20A", "Q22", 
    "Q23"), p2s = FALSE, incheck = TRUE)
imps_mck <- Amelia.imputation$imputations  

## here I had 20 imputed datasets with 24 binary questions ###
for (i in 1: 20) { 
    imps_mck[[i]]$COUNTRY <- factor(imps_mck[[i]]$COUNTRY) }  
### There are 3 different groups (countries) in the dataset ###

model_mck <- 'MCK = ~  Q1 + Q2A + Q3A + Q3B + Q3C + Q5 + Q6 + Q8A + 
    Q8B + Q8C + Q10 + Q12B + Q13A + Q13B + Q13C + Q17A + Q18B + Q19A +
    Q19B + Q19C + Q19D + Q20A + Q22 + Q23'

cfa.configural <- cfa.mi(model_mck, data = imps_mck, 
    estimator = "WLSMV", group = "COUNTRY", ordered = TRUE)
summary(cfa.configural, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)

cfa.metric <- cfa.mi(model_mck, data =  imps_mck, estimator = "WLSMV",
     group = "COUNTRY", ordered = TRUE, group.equal = "loadings")
summary(cfa.metric.amelia_mck_wout_Q9, fit.measures = TRUE, 
        standardized = TRUE)

cfa.scalar <- cfa.mi(model_mck, data = imps_mck, estimator = "WLSMV", 
                     group = "COUNTRY", ordered = TRUE,
                     group.equal = c("loadings","intercepts"))
summary(cfa.scalar, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)

### All models give very different and inconsistent fit indices and 
#   test statistics when I delete them from the R environment 
#   and re-run them ###

lavTestLRT.mi(cfa.metric, h1=cfa.configural)
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong with the codes? I couldn't find any information in the group chats and other platforms. It would be very appreciated if someone could take a look and help.

---

Might it be because of the fact that my model is too wide? I mean, too many questions exist for such small sample sizes.
Might it be because I did something wrong with the imputation method?
Or is it something like a program bug?
When I run the CFA models with 20 imputed datasets, sometimes the model converges on all 20 imputed data sets, and sometimes it doesn't converge for every imputed data set.
I also tried to run the model with fewer imputed datasets (m=5 or m=10), but it keeps giving inconsistent model fit results.
I can't figure this problem out even if I tried so many different ways.